# Why does Desura think it's already installed on my Mac?

Tags: macos, desura

When I go to [Desura's site](http://www.desura.com/) and click [Download Desura](http://www.desura.com/install), I get two options:

> Desura is installed
> Let's play!
>
> Install Desura
> For Windows

I've never been to the Desura site before. This machine is about 2 months old. I'm pretty certain Desura is not installed.

Clicking on "Let's play" does nothing. It's a link to `desura://refresh/`. I've tried running `open desura://refresh/` in the shell, and it appears that nothing on my machine recognizes the `desura:` URL scheme.

What makes Desura think that I have it installed already? How can I get the download URL?

Comment: Under the "For Windows" there's "(other versions)". Unfortunately that only brings up three buttons for me; Windows, Linux(64bit), and Linux(32bit).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Desura doesn't think you've installed it, it is offering you options how to proceed if it is installed or not - if you have the client installed you click the first button, if you don't you click the other button. There is no Desura client for OS X, but they do offer standalone OS X distributions through the site.

Comment: Can you explain what the difference is? And can you point to something that actually says that? I don't see any explanation like that on the site.

Comment: @Peeja what the difference is between what and what? http://www.moddb.com/forum/thread/desura-mac-client-install first hit for "desura mac client" Google search.

Comment: The difference between a client and a standalone distribution. After reading that thread I see what you mean: some games have standalone OS X versions. In this case, I'm trying to install original Half-Life 2 mod incarnation of The Stanley Parable. I guess I can't do it through Desura. Looks like there are other ways to install it on the Mac, though.